# Facebook c# sdk, silverlight4, login example please

Tags: silverlight-4.0, facebook-c#-sdk

What I would like to do is upload a photo to the fb user's wall. I have the photo in memory as a byte[] array.  The posting is not too much of a problem, but getting the user to log in first is where I am having the difficulty.  The documentation for the SDK in the web context is missing whole pages, and has 'TODO' all through the pages that do have content.

There is an SL4 sample, but my IDE (VWDE), does not support unit-test folders.  Searching though all the unit tests by hand, I still could not find one for logging the user in.  I have a facebook app already, no problem there.

There are a few gotchas that I have turned up:  Silverlight in-browser does not support the  control.  Also the Cassini web-server is not supported by the SDK.

If someone could post an example for this particular scenario, or a link to a sample, using the most recent version of the SDK, then I would be extremely grateful.

---

thank you Prabir.  Any pointers on the image upload? This is my code to-date.  It returns facebookOAuthError(#1)UnexpectedException.

```
        var fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(this.picProfile, null);
        string fileName = wb.SaveToPNG();
        byte[] data = convertToByteArray(wb);
        fb.PostCompleted += (o, e2) =>
        {
            if (e2.Cancelled) { var cancellationError = e2.Error; }
            else
                if (e2.Error != null) Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(e2.Error.Message));
        };
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["caption"] = "Fitness Tracker -- measurement of my weight over time";
        parameters["source"] = new FacebookMediaObject
        {
            ContentType = "image/png",
            FileName = fileName
        }.SetValue(data);
        fb.PostAsync("me/photos", parameters);
```

Many thanks,  M.R.

Answer (score 1):

you can find samples in the **v5** branch at https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-csharp-sdk/tree/v5/Samples